# how to implement in-app purchase in COCOS2dx in ios?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I am working on an game app of cocos2dX. I want to implement in-App purchase in this app. I followed [Link](http://soom.la/) but found nothing helpful. Please provide some sample code or tutorial to implement in app purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Look at: `plugin/samples/HelloPlugins/Classes` for the TestIAP example code.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out soomla. Works for iOS and Android. https://github.com/soomla/cocos2dx-store-example